# What is a reasonable setting for maxmemory on a Linux server with 10CPUs and 32GB of memory?

Tags: performance, redis, load, cpu-usage

I have been having performance issues on a RedHat Linux server.  The Load in Top keeps jumping to 100+ numbers causing users to hang.  When it jumps there I see redis-server as the top process using 97% of the CPU. I need to tune it so it won't spike that way.

I see this in the config file:
maxmemory 128mb
maxmemory-policy noeviction

For starters, it seems that 128mb is a very small piece of memory.  Perhaps it is overfilling and cause writes which cause CPU spikes?  And it appears that if the maxmemory-policy is set to volatile-lru it would clean up expired objects.  What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

128mb does seem very small. Assuming there is nothing else on the server, I'd set it to about 70-80% of the available physical memory. Setting it is really important, so it's good that it is set. If you don't set `maxmemory`, Redis will happily consume everything, including swap space. Not a good time.

The `noeviction` policy will result in errors when someone tries to set a key in Redis and it's out of memory. `volatile-lru` gets rid of the least-recently used keys if they have a TTL. If all your keys have a TTL, this will be fine. If they don't, you could still get an out of memory error from Redis as it fills up with persistent keys. So, `allkeys-lru` might be worth considering.

And if you want to be an absolute beast, you could always set your `maxmemory-policy` to `allkeys-random`!